# julia command not found even after adding to PATH

Tags: julia

I am not able to run a Julia file from the command line despite being able to use Julia fine from inside the REPL and Atom. I receive a `zsh: command not found: julia` error when I try that. Based on [this resource](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8733), I ran `export PATH="/Applications/Julia-1.4.2.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin:$PATH"` and `sudo ln -s /Applications/Julia-1.4.2.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia` but it did not resolve the issue. Is there anything else I could try?

edit: I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: What operating system and version you have? What happens when you try to run `/Applications/Julia-1.4.2.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia`

Comment: I had the name of the file wrong. It doesn't have patch version. Sorry for the basic mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe istead of editing the question it would be better if you responded to your own question and accepted that answer, it's recommended thing to do in SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ls -a /Applications/` showed that the file is actually named `Julia-1.4.app`